# k means algorithm python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, k-means

Whenever k = 2, the code runs in a loop
if k > 2 it sets all, but one of the centroids location to 0,0
I've reviewed it a couple of times , and it doesn't seem like there are any errors probably some sort of logic flaw. The code starts by having a class and its methods which initiate the centroids, calculate the Euclidean distance, and reassign centroids to the average positions of the points that are in the cluster. It then runs a loop that consists of reassigning and calculating distance until a list of the assignments are equal and then plots it.

```
class Kmeans:
    def __init__(self, K, dataset, centroids, sorting):
        self.K = K
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.centroids = centroids
        self.sorting = sorting
#sets starting position of centroids
    def initializeCentroids(self):
        bigX = 0
        bigY = 0
        self.centroids = []
        for i in self.dataset:
            if i[0] > bigX:
                bigX = i[0]
            if i[1] > bigY:
                bigY = i[1]
        for q in range(self.K):
            self.centroids.append([random.randint(0, bigX), random.randint(0, bigY)])
        plt.scatter((self.centroids[0][0], self.centroids[1][0]), (self.centroids[0][1], self.centroids[1][1]))
        return self.centroids
#calculates euclidean distance
    def calcDistance(self):
        self.sorting = []
        for w in self.dataset:
            print(w)
            distances = []

            counter = 0
            for centr in self.centroids:
                distances.append(math.sqrt(abs((centr[0] - w[0] * centr[0] - w[0]) + (centr[1] - w[1] * centr[1] - w[1]))))
                counter += 1
                if counter > 0:
                    try:
                        if distances[0] > distances[1]:
                            distances.pop(0)
                        if distances[1] > distances[0]:
                            distances.pop(1)
                            counter -= 1
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
            self.sorting.append([w, counter, distances[0]])
        return self.sorting

   

    def reassignCentroids(self):
        counter3 = 1
        for r in range(len(self.centroids)):
            positionsX = []
            positionsY = []
            for t in self.sorting:
                if t[1] == counter3:
                    positionsX.append(t[0][0])
                    positionsY.append(t[0][1])
            population = len(positionsY)
            if population == 0:
                population = 1
            self.centroids.append([sum(positionsX) / population, sum(positionsY) / population])
            counter3 += 1
            self.centroids.pop(0)
        return


k = 4
dataSetSize = input("Enter the amount of tuples you want generated: ")
data_set = []
for o in range(int(dataSetSize)):
    data_set.append((random.randint(0, 1000), random.randint(0, 1000)))
attempt = Kmeans(k, data_set, 0, 0)

attempt.initializeCentroids()

xvals = []
yvals = []
sortCompare = []
# plots

for p in data_set:
    xvals.append(p[0])
    yvals.append(p[1])


running = True


while running:

    if len(sortCompare) > 1:
        centroidChoice0 = []
        centroidChoice1 = []
        for p in sortCompare[0]:
            centroidChoice0.append(p[1])
        for d in sortCompare[1]:
            centroidChoice1.append(d[1])
        print(centroidChoice1)
        print(attempt.centroids)
        if centroidChoice1 == centroidChoice0:
            running = False
            for m in attempt.centroids:
                plt.scatter((attempt.centroids[0][0], attempt.centroids[1][0]), (attempt.centroids[0][1], attempt.centroids[1][1]))
            running = False
        sortCompare.pop(0)
    attempt.calcDistance()
    sortCompare.append(attempt.sorting)
    attempt.reassignCentroids()
```